# Error on getDomainClient

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have below code for domainClient. But I am getting error. Error is `'Argument 2 passed to Aws\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, string given`

```
$csDomainClient = $csClient->getDomainClient(
        'xxxxxxxxxxx'
);
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: you will need to pass second argument as array like  "array $args = []" and test, hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @user247217 Thank you. You mean like this?  `getDomainClient($domainName, $args = [])`

Comment: yes, i want like that $csDomainClient = $csClient->getDomainClient( 'test','DomainName' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx' );
actually you missed second argument which type an array

Comment: i will give you an example with "test" just, you can change as per your requirements

Comment: @user247217 Does this function still exist in aws version 3?